# Custom configuration file custom_config.js not working?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am trying to use a custom configuration file instead of the default config.js file in the ckeditor root.
I have placed a renamed copy of the config.js file in my webroot and call it with customConfig.
It is not working for me though. Is my syntax creating any issues?

I used the dev docs site as a ref:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/D ... igurations

Any ides or comments will really help me out. Im stuck.

Thanks!!

nano

```
135 <html>
136 <head>
137 <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
138 </head>
139 <body>
140 <form method="post">
141 <p>
142 <textarea name="ticket_text">&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
143 <script type="text/javascript">
144 CKEDITOR.replace( 'ticket_text' );
145 CKEDITOR.replace( 'ticket_text1',
146 {
147 customConfig : '/ckeditor/custom_config.js'
148 });
149 </script>
150 </p>
151 <tr>
152
153 <td></td>
154
155 <td align="right">
156
157 <input type="hidden" value="add" name="action">
158
159 <input type="submit" value=" Add Ticket ">
160
161 </td>
162
163 </tr>
164 </form>
165 </body>
166 </html>
```

Comment: "It is not working for me though" is not a very helpful error message - you're more likely to get a sensible answer if you are specific about what you expect vs what happans and quote any error mesages. Have you checked if there is a different version cached on the browser?

Comment: retagged, because this problem has nothing to do with `php` or `sql`

Answer (score 0):

In code example you aren't using the config against a valid form element.  You are replacing the text area ticket_text with a standard config in line 144, but in line 145 you are replacing a textarea ticket_text1, which doesn't exist in the form.

Also, in your description you said that you put the updated config into your webroot.  In the code you are referencing a config file in the ckeditor root.

When using CKEDITOR.replace you need to be replacing an element in the dom.